# How do I run each of my Junit 5 test as Privileged action?

Tags: junit, junit5

I am writing integration tests using Junit 5.
I should run each test with privileged action (as logged in user).

I could achieve it by calling using Subject.doAs from each test like this:

```
Subject.doAs(systemSubject, (PrivilegedAction<Object>) () -> actualMethodToBeTested();
```

But is there any way to achieve this by using Extension in Junit 5? The reason is to avoid calling the Subject.doAs in each method.

In Junit 4, I could achieve it with the use of test decorators and runners.

Simplified version of my Junit 4 runner:

```
@Override
public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        try {
            Object testObject = testClass.newInstance();
            for (Method method : testClass.getMethods()) {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)) {
                    notifier.fireTestStarted(Description
                            .createTestDescription(testClass, method.getName()));
                    final Subject systemSubject = getSystemSubject();
                    Subject.doAs(systemSubject, (PrivilegedAction<Object>)
                                            () -> {
                                                try {
                                                    return method.invoke(testObject);
                                                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                                                    return null;
                                                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                                                    return null;
                                                }
                                            });

                    notifier.fireTestFinished(Description
                            .createTestDescription(testClass, method.getName()));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: By `actualMethodToBeTested` do you mean the test method, or some "production" method the test calls?

Comment: Also, can you share the JUnit 4 runner you have?

Comment: Perhaps you can do something with a JUnit Test Template - this is what JUnit5 used to make Parameterized and Repeated tests - i.e execute tests in the same or similar context. Here is a link to JUnit 5 extension model, there is a section about that. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions

Comment: @Mureinik yes actualMethodToBeTested is the production method for which the test is written.

Comment: @Kotse, I have used ParameterizedTests when I want to run the same test with different cases. But what I want here is to run all the tests in all of my test classes as the logged in user. i.e., Subject.doAs(mySubject, (PrevilegedAction<Object>) () -> myTestMethod();
Custom runners helped me in junit 4. But how can I achieve the same using Junit 5 extension? Can you please suggest any simplified example to achieve this?

Comment: I have found that 5.4.0-M1 has implementation for Node.around() [link] (https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/1705/files) which helps to achieve this. I understood that I should call Node.around() inside Subject.doAs(). But I could not find any examples how to implement it. Can anyone explain in steps what should I do to implement that?
Note: Currently I am not using LauncherConfig or any custom test engines( Also, I am not familiar with those implementations too as of now).